# goals in cobertura plugin for maven 2 independent of each other?

Tags: maven-plugin, cobertura

in the cobertura plugin for maven 2 , are all the goals exclusive of each other ? as in .. what i want is that there should be a check as well as there should be report generation , when i use the cobertura goal in my build , check is not done .. when i use the check goal , reports are not generated , i had to use both goals to get what i desire , but then it runs the tests as many times .. this is what i am doing

org.codehaus.mojo
                cobertura-maven-plugin
                
                    
                        93
                        88
                    
     
      html
     
                
                
                    
                        verify
                        
                            cobertura
                            check

or is it that i am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the cobertura plugin in both areas. In the build area to do checkings and in the reporting area as well to get reports like the [docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html) says.
Whay not calling mvn site or mvn package ? If you configured it correct it will run as part of the phases.

Comment: I have already tried out using both package and verify phases.  I have also tried using check in the build and cobertura in reporting .

Comment: What are the results? any message?

Comment: no messages , reports are  not generated. i have gone through the docs already and didn't find the answer .. if possible can you post a chunk of pom configuration that you are suggesting